# Fitting data with Arrhenius Equation

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have the following data:

```
DataAZ400K = {{293, 1.98}, {313, 1.34}, {326, 1.58}, {344, 
    2.54}, {358, 3.8}, {373, 6.12}};
```

I want to fit this data with an exponential fit of the Arrhenius form $y \propto e^{-\frac{C}{k_{B}x}}$ where $k_B=1.38 \times 10^{-23}$ and $C$ is a fitting parameter. Ideally, I would also like to do the fitting in a $Log(y)$ v/s $1/x$ plot where the fitting should just be linear. How can I do the fitting in both linear plot and the second type $Log(y)$ v/s $1/x$.

Comment: Can you please help me with that in the log(y) vs 1/x plot?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried with `NonlinearModelFit` and/or `LinearModelFit` along with a description of any trouble you're having.  The documentation on those two functions should be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NonlinearModelFit and LinearModelFit both work well. The one caveat is setting the scale of the parameters since the Boltzmann constant has such a small numerical value.

Alternatively, you can include kB in the fit by fitting to, e.g., `A Exp[-Ck/x]` with fit parameters A and Ck. A good initial guess for Ck is the typical size of your x values, i.e., around 300.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[DataAZ400K, A Exp[-Ck/x], {{A, 1}, {Ck, 300}},x]
```

This gives a fit with values for A and Ck. The C parameter in your fit equals Ck times kB. Compare fit and data:

```
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 290, 380}], ListPlot[fit["Data"]]]
```

[image: nonlinear fit]

For linear fit, convert your data to the form `{1/x, Log[y]}` e.g.,

```
linearData = {1/#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ DataAZ400K
```

and then a linear fit as a function of a variable x1 standing for 1/x:

```
fitLinear = LinearModelFit[linearData, x1, x1]
```

and plot:

```
Show[Plot[fitLinear[x1], {x1, 1/400, 1/290}], ListPlot[fitLinear["Data"]]]
```

[image: linear fit]

To display the original y coordinates with the linear fit, exponentiate and plot with log scale:

```
 Show[LogPlot[Exp@fitLinear[x1], {x1, 1/400, 1/290}], ListLogPlot[{#[[1]], Exp[#[[2]]]} & /@ fitLinear["Data"]]]
```

[image: log scale for linear fit]

Comment: In the Log (y) vs 1/x plot, how can I make the y axis to display the real y values but in the log scale?

Comment: One way is exponentiate the y values and use Log plots. More generally, have a look at documentation for ScalingFunctions.